# select api failing in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Im trying to select the day value from a dropdown list.But the select api is failing

```
Select date=new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("dropdown_day")));
date.selectByIndex(5);
```

Code fragment is

```
<div id="dropdown_dropdown_day" class="dropdown" role="application" style="width: 32%;">
<input id="dropdown_day" type="hidden" value="0" name="dropdown_day">
<input id="btn_dropdown_day" class="btn-m btn-ter dropdown-toggle dropdown-input" type="text" style="min-height: 19px; width: 100%;" aria-haspopup="true" name="dp_dropdown_day" aria-owns="options_dropdown_day" aria-disabled="" role="combobox" readonly="readonly" title="" value="Day">
<i class="caret-dn-dp" aria-haspopup="true"></i>
<ul id="options_dropdown_day" class="dropdown-menu-dp" style="min-width: 60px; width: 100%;" aria-hidden="true" aria-activedescendant="" role="listbox">
<li class="op" aria-selected="true" tabindex="0" role="option" op-value="0">Day</li>
<li class="op" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1" role="option" op-value="1">01</li>
<li class="op" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1" role="option" op-value="2">02</li>
<li class="op" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1" role="option" op-value="3">03</li>
<li class="op" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1" role="option" op-value="3">...</li>
<li class="op" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1" role="option" op-value="4">31</l
</ul>
```

Comment: What is the fail error?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "input"
Build info: version: '2.37.0', revision: 'a7c61cb', time: '2013-10-18 17:15:02'
 os.name: 'Windows Vista', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.0', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select.<init>(Select.java:46)

Answer (score 0):

Your 'select' is an input. Html select would be `<select>`.

Looks like some JavaScript is transforming your input into select. If you use HtmlUnitDriver please enable JavaScript in it or try to use FirefoxDriver.

```
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
```

You maybe also need to wait second or half for JavaScript to be executed before calling your code.

Comment: WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.id("btn_dropdown_day"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",we);                                                                                      By using the above javascript the dropdown list has been clicked,but not able to select the value(Day) from the list